# How do you use flax.linen.checkpoint with static_argnums to allow a boolean argument to __call__?

Tags: python, jax, flax

I have a subclassed `flax.linen.Module` that takes a boolean argument in its `__call__` method. I want to use gradient checkpointing to reduce the GPU memory footprint of this layer, so I am using [flax.linen.checkpoint](https://flax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_reference/flax.linen/_autosummary/flax.linen.remat.html) which promises to be a "lifted" version of `jax.checkpoint`.

What I want is to use the standard pattern of passing a boolean flag into the `__call__` method to indicate whether we are in training or inference mode. In training mode, operations like dropout are random; in inference mode they are deterministic. So the flag variable is often named `deterministic`. So far this is all standard stuff.

The deterministic variable cannot be traced as it will affect control flow, so instead (when applying function transformations) it is usually flagged using `static_argnums`, as in [this example](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_autosummary/jax.checkpoint.html) from the jax.checkpoint documentation. Again, standard jax. What I want is to use this same pattern, but with the flax module.

I take the use of "lifting" in the documentation of `flax.linen.checkpoint` to mean that it can be used on a Module the same way `jax.checkpoint` can be used on a function. And indeed the documentation says it has a `static_argnums` parameter which (I think) should intuitively be applied to the `__call__` method of the (callable) Module, to allow non-traced values in the same way `jax.checkpoint` does.

However, I can't get this to work. See for example the following code, directly modeled on the example in the `flax.linen.checkpoint` docs:

```
import jax
import jax.numpy as jnp
import flax.linen as nn

class MLPWithDropout(nn.Module):
  @nn.compact
  def __call__(self, x, deterministic=False):
    x = nn.Dense(128)(x)
    x = nn.Dropout(rate=0.5, deterministic=deterministic)(x)
    x = nn.relu(x)
    x = nn.Dense(1)(x)
    return x

# The following fails with jax.errors.ConcretizationTypeError, and suggests using static_argnums:
CheckpointedMLPWithDropout = nn.checkpoint (MLPWithDropout)

# Specifically the error is this: 
#  jax.errors.ConcretizationTypeError: Attempted boolean conversion of traced array with shape bool[]..

# The following fails with a ValueError, and says that static_argnums (which has been remapped to 3) is too large:
# CheckpointedMLPWithDropout = nn.checkpoint (MLPWithDropout, static_argnums=2)

# The following does not seem to do anything, i.e. it returns a ConcretizationTypeError again:
# CheckpointedMLPWithDropout = nn.checkpoint (MLPWithDropout, static_argnums=-1)

# Same for this (ConcretizationTypeError):
# CheckpointedMLPWithDropout = nn.checkpoint (MLPWithDropout, static_argnums=1)

model = CheckpointedMLPWithDropout()
x = jnp.ones((1, 16))
rng = jax.random.PRNGKey(0)
vars = model.init(rng, x, deterministic=True)

print(model.apply(vars, x, deterministic=False, rngs = {'dropout': rng}))
```

Answer (score 1):

This turned out to be a very basic Python error: since I was passing `deterministic` as a named argument, it did not get counted as a positional argument. The following works:

```
CheckpointedMLPWithDropout = nn.checkpoint (MLPWithDropout, static_argnums=2)

...

vars = model.init(rng, x, True)

print(model.apply(vars, x, False, rngs = {'dropout': rng}))
```